# How to efficiently read in hexadecimal double data from a file?

Tags: matlab

The purpose is to losslessly save and exchange data from Matlab. For example, given a double array:

```
>> a
a(:,:,1) =
    0.8147    0.1270    0.6324
    0.9058    0.9134    0.0975
a(:,:,2) =
    0.2785    0.9575    0.1576
    0.5469    0.9649    0.9706
```

we can save the data as hexadecimal format into a file

```
fp = fopen('test.dat','w');
fprintf(fp, '%bX  ',a);
```

and get

```
3FEA1237688ABA7B  3FECFC3F5F570C7D  3FC0411A9F807B7C  3FED3A6000E256BF  3FE43C49753B9024  3FB8F8687182D4C0  3FD1D2EA3181CE68  3FE1800DABF8B5E0  3FEEA3E55FFC605B  3FEEE05DEBDEEB6B  3FC42CAA5B9D0950  3FEF0F1897ECA804
```

In turn, we need to read these data into Matlab correctly. However, there is no the corresponding "%bX" format in fscanf(). I have searched and could do it one-by-one:

```
for k = 1 : xx
    tmp = fscanf(fp,'%s  ',[1 1]); 
    b(k) = hex2num(tmp);
end
```

Since it is not efficient especially for large data, how to read in these data into Matlab efficiently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than looping, I would simply read the entire file in using `fread`, split it at all spaces using `strsplit` to create a cell array of strings where each hexadecimal number is an element and then use `hex2num` to convert each element from hexadecimal to a double.

```
fid = fopen('filename.dat', 'r');
numbers = hex2num(strsplit(fread(fid, '*char').'));
fclose(fid);
```

**Update**

If you don't have `strsplit`, you can use `regexp` to do the splitting for you.

```
numbers = hex2num(regexp(fread(fid, '*char').', '\s+', 'split'));
```

And another option is to use `textscan` to parse our each hexadecimal number

```
data = textscan(fid, '%s');
numbers = hex2num(data{1});
```

Comment: thank you. it seems that the function strsplit() exists only in the new version Matlab.

Comment: @lxg Updated with an alternative for older versions.